# SQLite rawquery return cursor empty object

Tags: sqlite, cursor

```
defHelper = new DefinitionSQLiteHelper(context, "Definitions", null, 1);
db = defHelper.getReadableDatabase();
if (db != null) { //Empezamos a leer de la BD
    args = new String[]{s+"%"};
    String[]campos=new String[]{"name","meaning"};
    String str = "SELECT * FROM Definitions";

    //SELECT name,meaning FROM Definitions WHERE name LIKE 'p%' ORDER BY name
    //Hago la búsqueda y lo guardo en un objeto Cursor
    c = db.rawQuery(str,null);

    //c.moveToNext();
    //Nos aseguramos de que exista al menos un registro en cursor
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
        //Guardar en array de letra
        do {
            //Aquí es donde guardo lo obtenido de la consulta en un array
            def.setPalabra(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            def.setSignificado(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            letraPrimera.add(def);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Here´s my code. Cursor object is empty, why? Any suggestions? I think that rawquery doesn't work good... But the RuntimeException is in this line:

```
def.setPalabra(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
```

My table has only two columns, the first in name and second is meaning. Two columns are Strings. Exceptions:

```
    12-07 22:42:07.295 2130-2130/com.example.juan.midiccionario E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                                at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                at com.example.juan.midiccionario.Letter.obtaninFirstPage(Letter.java:100)
                                                                                at com.example.juan.midiccionario.Page.<init>(Page.java:23)
                                                                                at com.example.juan.midiccionario.Search.onQueryTextSubmit(Search.java:127)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1156)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.access$900(SearchView.java:101)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$9.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1134)
                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6030)
                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5911)
                                                                                at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:720)
                                                                                at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
                                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9234)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2395)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1727)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2725)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:224)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3981)
                                                                                at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2253)
                                                                                at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1874)
                                                                                at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(Input
```

12-07 22:42:07.295 2130-2130/com.example.juan.midiccionario D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-07 22:42:07.295 2130-2130/com.example.juan.midiccionario E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.juan.midiccionario, PID: 2130
                                                                              java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                                  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                  at com.example.juan.midiccionario.Letter.obtaninFirstPage(Letter.java:100)
                                                                                  at com.example.juan.midiccionario.Page.(Page.java:23)
                                                                                  at com.example.juan.midiccionario.Search.onQueryTextSubmit(Search.java:127)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1156)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.access$900(SearchView.java:101)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$9.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1134)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6030)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5911)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:720)
                                                                                  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9234)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2395)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1727)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2725)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:224)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3981)
                                                                                  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2253)
                                                                                  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1874)

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: I edited with exceptions. I created an object Letter (this class) into another activity (Search).

Comment: The problem is not Exception, because object c is empty and has return -1 index, but it's created and it could invoke the method moveToFirst.

Comment: You said you get an exception on the line with `def.setPalabra`. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a new Definition objet (I only has declared but not initializated), and then it can works:

```
    //Conectar con la base de datos
        defHelper = new DefinitionSQLiteHelper(context, "Definitions", null, 1);

        db = defHelper.getReadableDatabase();


        if (db != null) //Empezamos a leer de la BD
        {
            //String con la consulta que vamos a hacer, con LIKE que va a indicar que empiece por la letra que acabamos de pasar
            String str = "SELECT name,meaning FROM Definitions WHERE name LIKE '"+s+"%' ORDER BY name";


            //Hago la búsqueda y lo guardo en un objeto Cursor
            c = db.rawQuery(str,null);

            //Nos aseguramos de que exista al menos un registro en cursor
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                //Guardar en array de letra
                do{
                    def = new Definition("","");//Creamos una definición vacía
                    def.setPalabra(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
                    def.setSignificado(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("meaning")));
                    letraPrimera.add(def);
                }while(c.moveToNext());

            }
            c.close();//Cerramos el cursor
            miIndice = 0;//apunto a la primera posición de letraPrimera
```

Thank you for the help.